# Как привязать свой OutputStream к консоли, не используя System.out/err?

Tags: java

Как можно вывести текст в консоль, не используя *System.out/err*?

Допустим, я хочу создать свой экземпляр класса *OutputStream*, и использовать его вместо *System.out*.

Как мне его привязать к консоли и при этом **вообще** не использовать *System.out*?

Варианты типа:

```
PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
```

Не подходят, т.к. используется *System.out*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out)
```

Comment: FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
f.write("Спасибо, добрый человек!".getBytes());

Answer (score -2):

Если я правильно понимаю то вы хотите просто избавиться от части System.out. Для того чтобы выводить текст в консоль посредством метода `print()` или `println()`. В таком случае добавьте в ваш код такие методы:

```
void print(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);
}
void println(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Ещё их можно поместить в отдельный пакет, который потом будет удобно импортировать в разные проекты.